# Constructing DFAs/NFAs What does the following notation mean: L = Σ* - λ

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-automata

I am just trying to figure out what the following notation means:

L = Σ* - λ

In regards to what "- λ" signifies. I know that "λ" means empty string, but I am not sure what "-" is implying.

Context: Construct a DFA or NFA (Deterministic/Non-deterministic Finite Automata) that accepts the language above where the alphabet is {0, 1}. My guess is that it means no empty strings are allowed? No idea. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It may be better suited to cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oops, yes you are right. Too late I guess, answers are already here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Σ*: All finite strings of the alphabet Σ

λ: The empty String

Σ* - λ: All finite strings of the alphabet Σ EXCEPT the empty string.

Both terms are sets, and - is the set difference.

Comment: Alrighty. So for my example, a possible DFA might have two states, the first state is a rejection state, and the second requires a "0,1" transition. Let me know if that sounds correct! Thank you.

Comment: That's correct. That second state should have a 0,1 transition to itself too.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda is usually the empty word, i.e. the language contains all non-empty binary strings.